# Setting up firewall using iptables

Tags: iptables, firewall

So, its getting more serious. I set up a "real" server. Before that I already configured firewalls using VMs. Now I got a question about which IP I need to allow, as I want to reject connections by default.

So lets say my local IP is `192.168.178.99` and my networks IP is `74.154.255.115`. 
I would suggest that I need to accept any connection from the networks address(`74.154.255.115`). But that would mean that anyone, who is using connecting to my router can access the server. 
Is there a some kind of common way to set up a secure server but still making sure I can connect to it from that specific device, not regarding the network the device is connected to?

Comment: You can set the source IP in the firewall rule to only allow connections from that source. Why don't you want to expose the server to the network anyway? What is the goal of your "real" server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since IP-addresses identify networks more than specific people you either simply trust a specific network and hope/take measures that the  people on that network won't / can't act with too much malicious intent.

The alternative is that you a set up a VPN server, which typically does allow you to assign a specific ip-address on the VPN to individual user and then create further firewall rules based on that VPN ip-address.

Answer (score 1):

> So lets say my local IP is 192.168.178.99 and my networks IP is
>   74.154.255.115. I would suggest that I need to accept any connection from the networks address(74.154.255.115).

Your router will simply *forward* the packet and thus hand you the original IP, unless it's NATing (and masquerading IPs). That is: incoming packets **won't have the IP of the router**. Think about it, if this were the case it would be literally impossible to send packets back and forth, because the effort for routers to "memorize" where a packet came from (originating IP) and where it was sent to (destination IP) would be gigantic. It'd simply impractical this way, which likely is the reason that it's not how the implementation works.

So the opposite is true. Your internal non-routable IP won't be visible to external parties as the router will take care of masquerading it (or you will have to, if you're the router), but incoming packets should still have the proper originating IP address. So your firewall rules, as far as external networks are concerned, will work just the same.

Now a setup like you describe it, sounds a bit like a home setup rather than the typical heavy duty server, but technically it's a server.

That said, it would still be better if the router would take care of the firewalling, rather than the machine that exposes any services. But that may not work in a home setup if the router doesn't provide this facility, for example.

I would also agree that blocking individual IP addresses or networks isn't too practical for many purposes. However, it works in one case: attacks (or as a subset: suspected attacks).

Say someone is trying to brute force their way into a service (say SSH) by means of a dictionary attack. You can then track their IP address with the `recent` module that comes with Netfilter and if they are trying too hard (i.e. too often within too short a period) you place them inside an [IP set](http://ipset.netfilter.org/). And all it takes then is a rule that drops or rejects packets coming from the IP set of offending IPs.